# changing max upload limit doesn't affect

Tags: upload, php.ini

A drupal website i run gets an error that says the php limit is 2Mb.
i changed it to 10 from /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini. 
This doesn't make any change (im using a phpinfo to look if any change to upload limit has happened). Can anyone suggest what can be done?

Comment: I had a similar issue where a size limit of 16Mb was displayed but the actual limit was 1Mb: after setting the size in the webserver's setting (nginx in this case) it worked as expected.

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting page on the [Drupal website](https://www.drupal.org/node/97193) about this, it was the first answer a well known search engine provided to `drupal file upload size`. THe second answer [also on the drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/422474) website is quite informative too.

> Drupal's limits on upload file size are determined by your server's PHP settings (as well as Drupal specified settings that can be set at Admin > Site Configuration > File Upload). The default values for PHP will restrict you to a maximum 2 MB upload file size.

it goes on to suggest that you may need to adjust both

- upload_max_filesize
- post_max_size

Comment: I remember a situation where I had to put the file size a multiple of 2 (I've put it 48MB instead of 45), otherwise some anomalies were occurring (cant remember the specifics), but it's a good to know thing.

Comment: I tried 10 and 12 so, they both are multiples of 2.

Comment: @lain i know that there is a portal for drupal. But this question i am having is about php upload limit. I just specified that i am using a drupal site on the webspace. I'm still stuck.

Comment: The thing about a SE Drupal site is that it will attract Drupal experts.